# How to kill script run by another script

Tags: python, shell

I'm working on following  script to automate enumeration phase.

I use subprocess to run nmap like this:

```
subprocess.run(["nmap", "192.168.1.1"])
```

I want to achive possibility to kill this subprocess and execute rest of code, but when i pick ctrl + c whole script run down.

Comment: Welcome. Could you please include the overall structure so that it could bring more clarity to the question?

Comment: of course  there  is line  of code like as above and user doesn't want to wait for the result of that command so how can he just skip it without killing whole script    `subprocess.run(["nmap", "192.168.1.1"]) ` - i don't want to wait for result of that command just skip to next

Comment: Please, provide example of your code, so that developers here can reproduce your error and help you with it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make **subprocess** in **try / except**:

```py
try:
    subprocess.run(["nmap", "192.168.1.1"])
except:
    print("Nmap Stopped.")
    pass
```

When you press **CTRL+C** an error will be occur and you handle it with **except** section.

Comment: No problem.
Just select this comment as answer if your problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Background it by doing :

```
ctrl+z
```

Comment: yes but it hang process, i want to kill just that one subprocess to execute rest of code

Answer (score 0):

this is where you should use `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.call` rather than `subprocess.run`

`subprocess.call` will be a blocking call, which mean it wait until the command finish and then it will move on with your code.

or another way is to put your `subprocess.run` in an `async` function and execute it separately

example

```py
import asyncio
async def run_nmap(ip:str):
    subprocess.run(["nmap", ip])

def run_the_thing():
    ...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(run_nmap("192.168.1.1"))
    ...
```